# how to add condition in xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-grouping

I am trying to parse is xml

```
<a>
    <b Number="first">
        <c Over="1">
            <name>1</name>
        </c>
        <c Over="2">
            <name>2</name>
        </c>
    </b>
    <b Number="Second">
        <c Over="1">
            <name>3</name>
        </c>
        <c Over="2">
            <name>4</name>
        </c>
    </b>
</a>
```

using grouping concept

I do like this

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common" exclude-result-prefixes="ext">
    <xsl:key name="node-by-over" match="c" use="@Over" />

    <xsl:template match="a">

        <xsl:apply-templates select="b[@Number='first']/c[generate-id() = generate-id(key('node-by-over', @Over)[1])]"/>

    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="c">
        <table id="">

            <xsl:for-each select="key('node-by-over', @Over)">
                <tr>
                    <td>balls:::<xsl:value-of select="name"/></td>

                </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**my output**

```
<table><tr><td>balls:::1</td></tr><tr><td>balls:::3</td></tr></table><table><tr><td>balls:::2</td></tr><tr><td>balls:::4</td></tr></table>
```

**expected**

```
<table><tr><td>balls:::1</td></tr><tr><td>balls:::2</td></tr></table>
```

why it is giving output like this 1,3,2,4 ??? I already use  mention in `applytemplate`I need all `c` node which @Number is `first`

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="b[@Number='first']/c[generate-id() = generate-id(key('node-by-over', @Over)[1])]"/>
```

expected output 1,2 (parsing of name)

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do.  I suspect that your use of keys is unnecessarily complicated -- you mention that you _"need all `c` node which @Number is `first`"_, which could be done much more cleanly without using any keys at all.  For your **expected** output, do you really just need the two `name` values contained within the topmost `b` element?

Comment: hi I able to solve my probm    <xsl:key name="node-by-over" match="b[@Number='first']/c" use="@Over" />

Answer (score 0):

Your expected output indicates that you want to have:

- a list of only the first `c/name` elements from each group
  (groupped by `Over` attribute),
- in a **single** `<table>` element.

(You should have written the above in your post).

So the essential changes to your script boil down to the following:

- Move `<table>` to `match="a"` template.
- Delete `<xsl:for-each` in `match="c"` template (to generate the output
  for **just the first** element from the current group).

And here is the complete script:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  <xsl:key name="node-by-over" match="c" use="@Over" />

  <xsl:template match="a">
    <table>
      <xsl:apply-templates select=
        "b[@Number='first']/c[generate-id() =
        generate-id(key('node-by-over', @Over)[1])]"/>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="c">
    <tr><td>balls:::<xsl:value-of select="name"/></td></tr>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

### Edit

Actually `[@Number='first']` in `select` is not needed, as the grouping selects just the first `c/name` element from each group, (gathered from the whole document).

Or if some other mechanism has already groupped elements (into *first* and
*second* group, maybe more), then the whole grouping based on `key`
is not needed.
Maybe just `select="b[@Number='first']"` would be enough.